# can I transfer a game app from galaxy s3 to galaxy tab 2

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-tab, file-transfer

just got a galaxy tab 2 today and I would like to transfer the fashion story game my daughter plays on my galaxy s3 phone to it so she doesn't have to start from scratch... she's 8 and found it sooo long to get where she is at

Comment: Is the game developed by `TeamLava Games`?

Comment: What Android versions are running on the devices? While [Sparx answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/45470/16575) looks good to me, it would require both devices to be rooted. You didn't mention whether they are?

Answer (score 1):

Use Titanium Backup to backup the game + data and then transfer the backup to your new device where you can use Titanium Backup on the new device to restore the app+data again.

However, please check whether the app is compatible with your new device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this app 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.traber.blueappsender

Using this app you can send the app to another phone or tab.

If you also need the data  simply copy the game data folder (mostly in android>data)